# Time format hhmm to hh:mm sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to find the time difference so i am trying to use **DATEDIFF** option.
But the problem is i am having the time values in hhmm format(eg: 1715). So it showing out of range error. so i want to convert it to hh:mm format. How to convert hhmm to hh:mm format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
DECLARE @TimeVal VARCHAR(4)
SELECT  @TimeVal = '1715'

select CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@TimeVal,2) + ':' + RIGHT(@TimeVal,2),8)
```

Output

```
1900-01-01 17:15:00.000
```