# need to Show time in HH:MM format only

Tags: sql-server-2008

i declare a field as **time** in sql. it is storing the date in the format as **HH:MM:SS**. now i want to retrieve the time value in the format **HH:MM**  and show it on the design view. is it possible to show time only in HH:MM? if so how to cast it as **HH:MM** format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130485/time-format-hhmm-to-hhmm-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    CAST(DATEPART(hour, '2007-06-01 12:15:22') AS nvarchar)+':'+
    CAST(DATEPART(minute, '2007-06-01 12:15:22') AS nvarchar);
```

Answer (score 1):

How it stores time is internal.

You can't change it in the designers etc because this is how SSMS formats it for display based on your regional settings

You can change to hh:mm using [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to (var)char(5) and style 108 when you query it, but I'd suggest you do this formatting in your client code.

Answer (score 0):

look at the t-sql function DATENAME:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, getdate()) AS 'Month Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

**for Am and Pm** 
SELECT substring(convert(varchar(20), GetDate(), 9), 13, 5)
+ ' ' + substring(convert(varchar(30), GetDate(), 9), 25, 2)

**for Date**

CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), GetDate(), 6)as log_date